# Create a nuget package from a NetCore2.1 project

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, nuget, dotnet-core-pack

I am struggling to get dotnet pack to generate a nuget package from a .NetCore2.1 project.

When I run dotnet pack from the cmd line the project is restored but then it goes no further.

Is this a limitation? I am struggling to find anything valuable online.

I am using AspNetCore.Mvc so moving to standard is not an option...

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you read [the guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x), what was the commandline you ran and what *exactly* happened (output)?. What did you expect to happen *instead*?

Comment: I managed to solve this with the help of Microsoft.

Their response:
What kind of project is it? 
A: xUnit

ASP.NET Core projects aren't packable by default, since you should use Razor class libraries instead.
(Which you could work around by setting <IsPackable>true</IsPackable> inside a <PropertyGroup>)

It seems to be only relevant to NetCore xUnit projects - https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1520

Answer (score 4):

ASP.NET Core and Xunit / test projects aren't packable by default. To create a package containing View assets, create a Razor class library instead. Or create a class library project for .NET Core.

Alternatively, you can add this to your csproj file to force the project to be packable:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Do not that these defaults have been put in place to prevent packages from creating unwanted side-effects or not behaving as expected so use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin says above, test projects are not packable, in my case, we had an unneeded reference to

```
Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk
```

Upon removing this reference I could package the project